one printer two wifi extender and wired network
I have a 1970's bungalow with cinder block walls. My ISP supplied a wireless router but due to the nature of construction and length of house, it only reaches the room it is in, the room behind it and into the main hallway.
I bought some powerline adaptors and extended the wired network through the power lines with those and connected two wifi repeaters to the powerline network one midway down the hallway and another at the end. I connected my printer directly to the power line network.
I wish to be able the share the printer across the whole network to be able to print from it in any room in the house.
However the printer a Brother MFC-J5330DW supports wifi and it has joined onto one of the repeaters ignoring the wired connection.
If I scan for wireless networks in the house, I find 3 one for the ISP router and the other two for the two repeaters and if you are on one of the other SSID the printer shows as off line.
I'm not sure the best course of action.

Do I need to configure the repeaters or router so all the "networks" trust each other?
If I get the printer to use the wired connection, does that mean its shared as they all point back to the ISP router?
Should I find a way to bridge the printer i.e. use the Wifi connection on one repeater and simultaneously use the wired connection for the ISP and I'm just not able to print from far end of house?

I'm not a network guy - so not 100% which path is viable. I read somewhere that the 3 SSID is required to allow a device to auto switch to the strongest signal is this true?

Wireless printing in my experience is extremely sensitive, I have found, unless both devices are connected to the same SSID the client will almost never find the printer. If the printer is ignoring the wired connection disable the wireless functionality.

"I read somewhere that the 3 SSID is required to allow a device to auto switch to the strongest signal is this true?" - Where exactly did you read this?

@Ramhound I've never had that issue with a non-smartphone/tablet, but with smartphones/tablets I usually have to manually search for the IP of the printer. I also set static IPs for all devices on my network, including the printer, so it helps to set the printer's static IP to something easy to remember (for example, the last two numbers of the IP are the model name, e.g. x.x.83.80)

Are walls bare cinder blocks or plaster/drywall (normally bare concrete walls only occur with poured concrete). If the latter, there are cavities between the studs you can run CAT6 up from the basement (preferable) or down from the attic extremely easily. Are the repeaters all configured with the same subnet mask? Does the printer show it's connected to WiFi when it shows offline from a WiFi client? WiFi extenders should be seamless - e g. IIRC the WiFi client should keep the same IP as the one provided by the main router, so manually connecting to the repeaters shouldn't need to be done.
